# Where should I store a user ID key in spring / spring-security in a webapp?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

Once a user is authenticated I have an Object userID.

Where is the "best" place to store this in Spring using Spring-Security (this is a webapp)?

- Session seems inelegant, because then I have two locations managing authentication (I need special code to manage removing the sesion object when the user is logged out for whatever reason)
- The currentContext.getAutentication().getDetails(...) seems complicated because it is seems to generate the details object per request

There are many options, but the best seems to be somewhere close to the Spring-Security authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the question. You don't have to store it. The are multiple ways to get it.

1. SecurtiryContextHolder if you need the UserDetails object
2. request.getRemoteUser() if you need only the loginId

Comment: The SecurityContextHolder only allows you to return a String username, not an arbitrary Object. I ended up extending the authentication mechanism so that I return my own custom Authentication object which supports adding arbitrary objects to a Map, allowing me to tack on extra Objects that are necessary and keep it tightly coupled to the whole authentication process.

Comment: Would you be willing to privde some code or more details on your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't belive that the authentication details are created for each request. I belive they are created once per authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it strongly depends on the way you use the userID.

For example: if you need the userID deep within you business service layer, and the business server layer is implemented nothing to know about web application stuff (Session, ...) up to now, then it would be wise not to use a HttpSession, to keep it "web stuff free".

BTW:
A third approach way you can taken in account, is to use a session scope bean.

Comment: I want to access the userID object in the controller, from there I will pass it as a parameter to services. The SecurityContextHolder seemed logical to keep it coupled with the authentication mechanism, but there's no easy way to do that that I saw. Session wasn't great because then I have to write code to update the session on login/logout. I just wondered if another common approach existed that people use. Lots of my service methods need this as the key to look up data in the DB for a given user.

Comment: @Czar:  `@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`  -  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other